# Only two properties of the model are updated

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I defined entity presented below:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Call> Calls { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to updated fields of the entity in the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("CustomerId,FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,Email")] Customer customer)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Update(customer);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(customer);
}
private readonly CustomerContext _context;
```

All values of the model have changed in the view and have been passed correctly to the method. `ModelState` is valid. All of the methods are executed, but after all in the database only `FirstName` and `LastName` are changed. Other properties not. I checked SQL which is executed:

```
UPDATE [Customers] SET [FirstName] = @p0, [LastName] = @p1
WHERE [CustomerId] = @p2;
```

Why other properties are not updated?

View Code:

```
<h4>Customer</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="CustomerId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CustomerContext.cs

```
public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext(DbContextOptions<CustomerContext> options): base(options){ }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasAlternateKey(cu => cu.PhoneNumber);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasAlternateKey(cu => cu.Email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Prove that all values have been passed correctly from the view to the method, hit a break point in Visual Studio, Quick Watch the customer model and take a screenshot of its values and a screenshot of the values you entered in the view

Comment: Also I strongly doubt you need that Bind statement, it is could be the source of your issue, ASP.NET MVC will deserialize the customer correctly without that bind statement

Comment: I checked it was passed correctly

Comment: Removing `Bind` doesn't change anything

Comment: Can we see your **ViewCode** please. I think something wrong on your view.

Comment: I added View code

Comment: @pw94 your view look like good and can we see your **Repository Class**  please

Comment: Added expected code

Comment: You have specified `Email` and `PhoneNumber` as alternate key columns. Keys should not be modified which is probably why they are being omitted from the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the source of the problems are alternate key columns, because keys are omitted. I removed them and replaced them with the index and everything works.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasIndex(cu => cu.PhoneNumber).IsUnique();
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasIndex(cu => cu.Email).IsUnique();
```

Comment: Alternate keys should have given you an exception (on save) if you modified those properties, not a partial update.